# Get url parts without host

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a url like this :

http://www.somesite.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye.

I want to get mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye from it . Can you tell me how can I get it ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Like this:

```
new Uri(someString).PathAndQuery
```

Comment: To which namespace "Url" class belongs to? Are you sure it's Url and not Uri?

Comment: It's Uri, not Url.

Answer (score 44):

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.somesite.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye");

string pathOnly = uri.LocalPath;        // "/mypage.aspx"
string queryOnly = uri.Query;           // "?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye"
string pathAndQuery = uri.PathAndQuery; // "/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye"
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your string URL into a URI object and then use the AbsolutePath & Query properties to get the URL parts you need.

Or use the PathAndQuery property to get both, which is what you need.

More information can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_members%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

new Uri(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Segments