# illegal characters in Path.Combine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, path, ftp

I have an ftp path that looks like this:
ftp://my|user|name:mypassword@example.com/Test/file.txt

I'm trying to use two functions from `Path`:
1. `Path.GetDirectoryName`
2. `Path.Combine`

Both return "illegal character in path".
What is the best solution to solve this problem? I need to get directory and I need to combine it with different file url.

Comment: I think `Path` is used for file paths on disk (your local machine), not URIs.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Uri` class to extract Path portion, than use `Path` class to manipulate it.

Use `UriBuilder` to construct it back.

```
var fullPath = 
  new Uri(@"ftp://my|user|name:mypassword@example.com/Test/file.txt")
     .AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but your code returns `/Test/file.txt` not `ftp://my|user|name:mypassword@example.com/Test/`

Comment: @user194076, because it *is path*. I guess you want something else (i.e. your definition of "path" is not the one from [Uri RFC](www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) ). I believe classes I've mentioned should give you way to do what you want in safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the path and query string from a uri, you can use `new Uri(someString).PathAndQuery` as seen in answer [Get url parts without host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619277/get-url-parts-without-host)

To combine Url or Uri, you may use the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23399048/3481183

The `Uri.Combine` function described in that answer was tested for combining ftp parts as well.

[image]